# Linkedin oauth - how to send access_token to request user profile data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to access user profile information from the LinkedIn API using Angular, Node.js, and the node-linkedin npm module. I have the first two parts completed (getting the code, and getting the access_token). So, I now have my user authenticated, and I have their access_token, but I can't figure out how to send that token in my HTTP request to pull their profile data.

So my first three routes look like this (they are in a controller and they are all get requests):

```
linkedInReq: function(req, res){
    Linkedin.auth.authorize(res, ['r_basicprofile']);
},
linkedInCallback: function(req, res){
    Linkedin.auth.getAccessToken(res, req.query.code, function(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;
        var user = new User({
            linkedin: JSON.parse(results)
        });
        user.save();
        res.redirect('/main');
    });
},
getMain: function(req, res){
    res.render('main'); 
},
```

This is working fine, and 'results' in the linkedInCallback route contains the access token (user.linkedin). Now, I have one last route to request the user profile data that looks like this:

```
getProfile: function(req, res){
        var linkedin = Linkedin.init(access_token_goes_here);
        linkedin.people.me(function(err, $in){
            res.send($in);
        });
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to get the user's access token so I can pass it to the Linkedin.init method. The getProfile route is being hit by an Angular $resource in a factory connected to my controller. I've tried every possible solution I can think of, but I'm at a loss. This is my first time trying to make an API connection with oauth.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but consider making a TokenStorageService and using it to pass the token around.  If you need to keep the token even if the app reloads then store it in window.localStorage which is outside of angular.  There is a ngStorage module which wraps it.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how to handle the access token. I'm getting it with the 'getAccessToken' method, and it's being stored to the user, but how do I access that data in my 'getProfile' route so I can pass it to the '.init()' method?